# Derivative of antipodal map between $n$-spheres

Tags: derivatives, manifolds

> Let $S^{n-1}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ denote the $(n-1)$-sphere $x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2=1$. Let $f:S^{n-1}\rightarrow S^{n-1}$ be the map $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=(-x_1,\ldots,-x_n)$. What is the derivative of $f$ at $p\in S^{n-1}$?

The derivative of $f$ at $p$ is the map from the tangent space $T_pS^{n-1}$ to the tangent space $T_{f(p)}S^{n-1}=T_{-p}S^{n-1}$.

It takes the vector $(p,v(p))$ to the vector $(-p,Df(p)\cdot v(p))$. We have $$Df(p)\cdot v(p) = -I_{n\times n}\cdot v(p)=-v(p).$$

So the derivative of $f$ at $p$ takes $(p,v(p))$ to $(-p,-v(p))$.

Is that right, and is there something else we can say?

Comment: For what it's worth, $n$-sphere always refers to the $n$-dimensional manifold consisting of unit vectors in $\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$.  Your space is the $(n-1)$-sphere.

Comment: It is right and there is nothing else to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's right. Perhaps the only thing to note is that the domain of the derivative map is the tangent space $T_pS^{n-1}$, so $v(p)$ is not just any vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but a vector in $T_pS^{n-1}$.